# Why would predicting a percentage bring my test score R2 nearly to zero?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am trying to predict the Score on an exam from various predictors. The exam have a total # of points (ScoreMaximum) you can have and each exam can have a different ScoreMaximum.

When I try to predict the variable Score and include ScoreMaximum as a predictor, I get a reasonable R2 from my models.

But then if I try to predict Score/ScoreMaximum * 100 without including ScoreMaximum as a predictor I get an R2 near 0.

I am trying to figure out why this might happen. I am conceptually predicting the same thing, but just differently... My main hypothesis is that the scale of the errors gets magnified when we divide by ScoreMaximum and the model gets far worse... This happens using several ML algorithms so this doesn't seem to be algorithm specific.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you fitting a linear model to these data?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen I am fitting xgboost specifically, but I had the same problem fitting a linear model using PyMC3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I thought there was a deeper explanation to this and I'll include it below because it is also important to know. But I think in your case the problem is actually rather superficial. You started out by predicting Score by ScoreMaximum. These two variables are pretty much guaranteed to be linked, as you can't score higher than the maximum on any exam. So unless scores are always really low (which wouldn't make sense because it would suggest that people consistently get a certain number of questions right, rather than a certain fraction), the upper bound (ScoreMaximum) will be quite strongly correlated to the average. So, ScoreMaximum may be accounting for a large fraction of the $R^2$ of your initial model fit. (This is similar to how the number of people that live in a city is a very good predictor of who many women live there.)

If you normalize scores by their maximum, this trivial relationship disappears, and so the variance explained drops considerably. The fact that the remaining $R^2$ is quite low suggests that the other predictors simply aren't very good.

---

The deeper explanation (which I don't think actually underlies your findings) was this:

You are applying a non-linear transformation to your data. Fitting the same model to data sets with different transforms will not give the same (and possibly not even similar) results. For instance, if your data is very well fit by a linear regression model, then that linear relationship will be distorted or destroyed by applying a non-linear transformation to your data.

That is, if your data $y$ are described by a standard linear model like this:
$$y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$
where $X$ is a matrix with your predictors in its columns, $\beta$ is a vector of coefficients and $\varepsilon$ is random (e.g. Gaussian) noise, then if we apply a non-linear transformation $f(\cdot)$ we get:
$$
f(y)=f(X\beta+\varepsilon)
$$
And, importantly:
$$
f(X\beta+\varepsilon)\neq X\beta+\varepsilon
$$
So, the same model that was a good fit to $y$ isn't going to be a good fit to $f(y)$ (even if you refit the parameters of the model).

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I needed to hear.  I focused on the mirage that my predictors had predicting power for my response variable, but sometimes the easiest response is the right one, my predictors don't have much signal.

Comment: +1 I think your first explanation (at the top) is very clear and a great explanation of the phenomenon likely occurring.